# Bizarre do..while behaviour: can you explain?

Tags: javascript, do-while

Consider the following block of code, run repeatedly ( [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DaW5D/) ):

```
var length = 50,
  xOffset = 0,
  yOffset = 0;
for (var a = 0; a < 100; ++a) { // just so we can see it "break"
  for (var l = 1; l <= length; l++) {
    var percentComplete = l / length,
      scaledPercent = (.5 - Math.abs(percentComplete - .5)) * 2,
      shake = 0,
      shakeTries = 0,
      deviationCeil = Math.ceil(10 * scaledPercent);
    if (Math.random() < .1 || Math.abs(xOffset) > deviationCeil)
      do {
        shake = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
        if (++shakeTries > 100) throw "X shake exceeded"
    }
    while (Math.abs(xOffset + shake) > deviationCeil);
    xOffset += shake;
    shakeTries = 0; // if we set shake = 0 here, everything works!
    if (Math.random() < .1 || Math.abs(yOffset) > deviationCeil)
      do {
        shake = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
        if (++shakeTries > 100) throw "Y shake exceeded"
    }
    while (Math.abs(yOffset + shake) > deviationCeil);
    yOffset += shake;
  }
}
```

When run repeatedly, the "Y shake exceeded" exception is thrown (the "X shake exceeded" is never thrown).

The solution is to set `shake` to 0 just before the Y block: `shake = shakeTries = 0`.

I don't see why this should be the case. In both blocks we start by assigning to shake, so it really shouldn't matter what the hell `shake` was, prior to going into the `do` block. My understanding of `do...while` (and the reason I'm using it) is that it executes its block first before testing the condition.

So why does it fail (not every time) when I don't reset `shake` before the `do` block?

Comment: could you please indent the code correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This weird behavior becomes more visible if we put in some additional `{` and `}`. Lets first look at just the X section. At the start, both shake and shakeOffset equal 0.

```
if (Math.random() < .1 || Math.abs(xOffset) > deviationCeil) {
  do {
    shake = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
    if (++shakeTries > 100) throw "X shake exceeded"
  } while (Math.abs(xOffset + shake) > deviationCeil);
}
xOffset += shake;
```

At this point, shake has whatever value was last used in the previous block (-1, 0, or 1). Then we get to the Y section:

```
shakeTries = 0; // if we set shake = 0 here, everything works!
if (Math.random() < .1 || Math.abs(yOffset) > deviationCeil) {
  do {
    shake = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
    if (++shakeTries > 100) throw "Y shake exceeded"
  } while (Math.abs(yOffset + shake) > deviationCeil);
}
yOffset += shake;
```

If we don't meet the condition that `(Math.random() < .1 || Math.abs(yOffset) > deviationCeil)`, then we skip the `do...while` entirely and add the value of shake from the X section to yOffset.

Comment: I wanna say this is right but I switched the places of the two sections and then it doesn't throw

Comment: Oh man. I knew it was something in my logic - and when you point it out it becomes so __obvious__! Thanks for taking the time. It all comes down to that Math.random() < .1 piece which was a late addition. Thanks again! Great explanation.